# Personalize indentation for new C++ language features

Tags: indentation, c++, cc-mode

I'm starting to use C++-17, and one of the new features is `if constexpr`, which breaks completely the usual `if` identation:

```
int main()
{
    if constexpr(true) {
            return 1;
        } else {
        return 0
            };
}
```

and without the brackets:

```
int main()
{
    if constexpr(true)
                    return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it? Even a dirty trick like telling emacs to treat the pattern `if constexpr` as equivalent to `if` is enough.

**NOTE:** I've discover the [`c-noise-macro-names`](http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/html-manual/Noise-Macros.html) variable, but I don't know even how to add an element to it (I've tried with `add-to-list` `push`, and `setq`, because it seems that it initially doesn't exist, without success).